# Spark-submit on Yarn throws NoSuchMethodError at spark.network.util.JavaUtils.byteStringAs

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Spark submit results in NoSuchMethodError.

## Spark Submit

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster 
                   --class batch.BatchJob /vagrant/spark-lambda-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar 
                   --conf userClassPathFirst=true --verbose
```

## Error

> 17/10/01 01:21:31 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw
>   exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.byteStringAs(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/network/util/ByteUnit;)J
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.byteStringAs(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/network/util/ByteUnit;)J
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigHelpers$.byteFromString(ConfigBuilder.scala:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder$$anonfun$bytesConf$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder$$anonfun$bytesConf$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.createWithDefault(ConfigBuilder.scala:142)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.(SQLConf.scala:158)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.(SQLConf.scala)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.(StaticSQLConf.scala:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.(StaticSQLConf.scala)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:843)
>     at batch.BatchJob$.main(BatchJob.scala:81)  at
>   batch.BatchJob.main(BatchJob.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:558)

Comment: Is this conf `userClassPathFirst=true` necessary for your jar ? Is there a conflict between bundled dependencies and the environment jars ?

Comment: Hi user238607, no it is not necessary. I was following a suggestion I had found on another thread. But it made no difference.

Comment: Then most likely, the error seems because of spark version mismatch. Are you sure that you are not bundling spark jars into the uberjar?